# How to disable groovy optimizations in maven

Tags: java, maven, groovy, pom.xml, jacoco

I know you can disable groovy optimizations in gradle:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(':cobertura')) {
        compileGroovy.groovyOptions.optimizationOptions.all = false
    }
}
```

But how do you do this in maven?

I want to do this so the code coverage generated by jacoco would make more sence